# PHP MySQL session connection database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, session

This is a long question so apologies. I have the following code.

```
 $register="SELECT * from register WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['username']."'";

$re = $connect->query($register);

$numrow = $re->num_rows; 

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo"<th>Username</th>";
echo"<th>Forename</th>";
echo"<th>Surname</th>";
echo"<th>Course</th>";
echo"<th>Subject</th>";
echo"<th>Level</th>";
echo"<th>Date</th>";
echo"<th>Time</th>";
echo"</tr>";

$count = 0;
while ($count < $numrow) 
{
$row = $re->fetch_assoc();
extract($row);    
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>";
echo $username;
echo "</td>";

 echo "<td>";
 echo $firstName;
 echo "</td>";

 echo "<td>";
 echo $surname;
 echo "</td>";

 echo "<td>";
 echo $course;
 echo "</td>";

 echo "<td>";
 echo $subject;
 echo "</td>";

  echo "<td>";
   echo $level;
 echo "</td>";

 echo "<td>";
 echo $date;
 echo "</td>";

 echo "<td>";
 echo $time;
 echo "</td>";

 $count = $count + 1;

 }
 ?>
```

The idea is that the page gets the session username (the user currently logged in) and then displays the relevant information based on that user. But unfortunately no results are displayed.

With the following code:

```
$register="SELECT * from register";
```

All of the details are shown from every user, which is correct because that is the query. I have the following code:

```
<?php
require "dbconn.php";

$reg="SELECT * from students WHERE username = '".   $_SESSION['username']."'";

$res = $connect->query($reg);

$numrow = $res->num_rows; 

$count = 0;
while ($count < $numrow) 
{
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
extract($row);    

$count = $count + 1;
}         
?>

<h2>Sign the Register</h2>
<form action="sign.php" method="post">
<div><textarea name="username" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true"  required="true"> <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="firstName" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true"  required="true"><?php echo $firstName;?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="surname"  rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true"  required="true"><?php echo $surname;?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="course"  rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true" required="true"><?php echo $course;?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="subject" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Please Enter  Your Subject..." required="true"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="level" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true required="true"         
<?php echo $level;?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="date" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true" required="true">
<?php date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"); echo date('Y-d-m');?      
</textarea></div><div><textarea name="time" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true" required="true"> 
<?php date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"); echo date('H:i:s A');?
</textarea></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Sign Register"></div>
</form>
```

And sign.php is:

```
{
   if(array_key_exists('username', $_POST) && array_key_exists('firstName',   $_POST) && array_key_exists('surname', $_POST) && array_key_exists('course',  $_POST) && array_key_exists('subject', $_POST) && array_key_exists('level',  $_POST) && array_key_exists('date', $_POST) && array_key_exists('time', $_POST))
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO register (username, firstName, surname,  course, subject, level, date, time) VALUES (:username, :firstName, :surname,  :course, :subject, :level, :date, :time)');
     $stmt->execute(array(':username' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']),
     ':firstName' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstName']),
     ':surname' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']),
     ':course' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['course']),
     ':subject' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']),
     ':level' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['level']),
     ':date' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']),
     ':time' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['time'])));
      $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount(); 
       }
```

So all of the sign and register page work fine. All of the correct data is sent and can be shown in the database. But when I specify the user to be shown, via the WHERE clause shown above, no results are shown.

But there is a user with the username of i001. If I manually type in the following query using the command line:

```
INSERT INTO register (username, firstName, surname, course, subject,   level, date, time) VALUES ('i001','Tom', 'Sm', 'Sociology',   'IntroductionToSociology', 'I','11.05.2015','15.05');
```

Then that result is shown when the user i001 is logged in, so that works fine. But using the register and sign.php form then it will not work. But regarding the register, the following code:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>
```

Does display the correct user logged in. And all of the data typed in the form does save correctly to the database. But will not be shown with the WHERE session username clause is present.

So basically any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT: It has something to do with the form/query. If I type in the query manually using MySQL Client it works perfectly. But when I type in using the form, it is sent to the database but not in the correct order. So not getting the correct username etc

Comment: echo your query and see,, any error shown

Comment: There is no error with the query..its something to do with the session

Comment: just echo and show me the query .. check if the session variable is passed to query

Comment: It is passed..all of the data is..from the command line using MySQL Client I can view that the data has been added, and it has been added when I use: $register="SELECT * from register"; just not with the Session part

Comment: that's my point is the session variable been fetched or not in the query

Comment: I'm sorry i'm a beginner so I don't really know what that means

Comment: I take it it hasn't been fetched

Comment: `'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "' ` try replacing this and let me know

Comment: Ok will do..but what page do I put that? where abouts?

Comment: I have put them on both sql queries and nothing has changed..any ideas?